# Error function for (linear) regression that punish less over-estimates?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, loss-functions

I have a regression problem that I currently train using the classic squared error loss. The thing is that my problem does not fit to this kind of loss:  I want to punish the model less when it over estimates the outcome, then when it underestimates it. For example, I would like to have something like that:

$y = 10, \hat{y} = 8 \rightarrow L(y, \hat{y}) = (10 - 8)^2$

$y = 8, \hat{y} = 10 \rightarrow L(y, \hat{y}) = |10 - 8| / const / ?$

Is there a loss function that achieves this?

Comment: So, you would be happiest with a upper envelope to the data, e.g. the upward-pointing part of a convex hull? That never understimates the data.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is ill-posed. The perfect solutions would be +infinity, +1e100, +1e90, etc. Your directive says: just overestimate the truth strongly enough and you will never get punished.

Comment: You are right. I modified the question.

Comment: Thanks. There are many approaches to the modified formulation of your problem. For example, you can transform the data: X' = log(X), Y' = log(Y). Then you can apply regular square loss minimization to X' and Y'. This way situation Y_Hat = Y - E will be penalized more than situation Y_Hat = Y + E (for E > 0).

Comment: See also quantile regression which except for the median case is a problem centred on asymmetric loss functions.